# type casting in C

Tags: c++, c, casting

```
int p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and,

```
int p = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

could anybody explain me what occurs internally and what the difference between using `(int*)` and `(int)`? 
Thanks.

Comment: Both of these things are very wrong, and you should never do either.

Comment: Which is it: C or C++? The answer will be fundamentally different depending on this.

Comment: @Jon Since the question is tagged C++ also, the cast to `int *` may be necessary. But then again, there's very little reason to use `malloc` instead of `new` in C++.

Comment: @Praetorian: The main problem though is the conversion to `int`.

Comment: You are assigning incompatible types.The compiler warning should be enough indication.You are assigning a pointer `int*` to an integer variable `int p`.In the second statement you are casting a pointer to an integer value.This may suppress warnings,but the first statement is wrong.

Comment: I think this is properly called, simply, *casting*. *Type-casting* is when you see the same actor in the same kind of role in many different theatrical or cinematic performances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is tagged C++ I'll take the C++ angle to the answer:

```
int p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
int p = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Both of these are wrong, malloc returns a pointer to some memory. I think what you actually wanted was to allocate an int on the heap, thus your return value is int*.

Depending on 32 or 64bit arch this code will break because you are going to assign 64bits of data to 32bits of storage.

The correct way in C is:

```
int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Which is saying, allocate enough space for the type int, and store a pointer to this allocated space. No cast is required in C.

In C++ it would look like this if you used malloc:

```
int* p = static_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int)));
```

Now the cast IS required, however you can avoid this by using operator new:

```
int* p = new int; // much cleaner!
```

Note that operator new will throw std::bad_alloc on failure rather than returning nullptr/0/NULL.

If you don't want it to throw but want the cleaner syntax you can use:

```
int* p = new (std::nothrow) int;
```

Or even better still, either don't allocate on the heap unless really needed, or use a smart pointer so you don't have to worry about calling operator delete or free():

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int); // when p leaves scope, the memory is deleted
```

Answer (score 10):

Both of your examples are "bad".

The first one is incorrect, as it tries to assign a pointer to an integer, and thus should at the very least give a warning, more likely an error. And if the machine is 64-bit and you are compiling it as 64-bit code, the pointer may not fit in the integer [same applies to a 16-bit int on a 32-bit machine, but that's not very common these days].

The second example will most likely compile, but it's still assigning an integer with the value of a pointer, which is pretty much pointless (and it may not fit, as pointers are bigger than `int`).

In "C", you should not use casts to assign the value returned by `malloc` - it is wrong, and can lead to problems.

In "C++", you should not use `malloc`, use `new` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`(int *)` is a cast to a **pointer to an integer**
`(int)` is a cast to an **integer**

They are quite different concepts in their own right. See this [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html) for more on pointers and how/when you should use them. They are a fundamental to C programming (and I would argue it's important to understand indirection as a concept as it pervades programming in general).

Comment: You are missing the key issue. Whatever the casts, a pointer is converted to an int.

Answer (score 3):

You are allocating a pointer to `int` – i.e. `int*` yet you are trying to assign the result to an `int`. That does not work.

In C, you do not need, and should not use, a cast:

```
int *pi = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

In C++, the cast is required but the `(…)` cast syntax (called “C-style cast”) is discouraged, as is the usage of `malloc`, for that matter. So syntactically correct C++ would be

```
int* pi = static_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int)));
```

However, *good code* would be either (a) avoiding the pointer allocation entirely, (b) using a ready-made class that handles the allocation, such as `boost::optional<int>`, or, as a last resort, using a smart pointer (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<int>`). If, for unfathomable reasons, you actually want to *manually* allocate and handle memory in C++, use either the `new` operator or an allocator class (such as `std::allocator`). Use `malloc` in C++ code only if you are passing memory to a C API which *explicitly* requires you to allocate memory for its arguments via `malloc`. This is the *only* valid use of `malloc` in C++.

Comment: sizeof(pi) is broken, it should be sizeof(int) since sizeof(pi) becomes sizeof(int*) which will change depending on 32 or 64bit

Comment: @paulm Right you are; I actually meant `*pi` but that becomes cryptic for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment should be:

```
int * p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

malloc returns void * (always a pointer), which you would then want to cast to the appropriate pointer type, such as int *.  It's also important to free() the allocated memory when you're done using it, to prevent a memory leak.  I assume your example is academic, as there are few cases where you'd want/need to allocate an int on the heap.

Comment: Woah... before you jump the gun, make sure you're actually answering the question.

Comment: And actually [you should not be casting the return value of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) in C.

Comment: Casting the return value of `malloc` is correct for C++ but not advised for C.

Comment: @GrahamBorland Why is it advised for C++ but not C?

Comment: In C, the types `void*` and `/*pointer to any object*/` are compatible. In C++ they aren't.